# Navigation: Distance between Waypoints in Global Path

Tags: ros, navigation, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I was wondering how the distance between the waypoints is determined in the global planner, and is it possible to increase this distance (i.e. decrease the number of waypoints) on the global path?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195792/navigation:-distance-between-waypoints-in-global-path/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently, the only way to do this is to decrease the resolution of underlying costmap.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-10-23**:
Thanks. So the distance between the waypoints is basically the distance between the adjacent cells of the costmap grid? and How can I decrease the resolution of the costmap?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-10-24**:
For the global planner, it is likely the same as the resolution of your static map. Otherwise there's a parameter that changes it, sneakily called "resolution" :)

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-10-24**:
Thanks David